# Stop/Start audio of another application

Tags: c#, windows, audio, cscore

Is it possible to reset (stop/start) audio from another applications using [CSCore Audio Library](http://cscore.codeplex.com/)?

I can activate windows effects from "enhancements" tab in speaker properties, but it won't start working until I restart the applications playing audio. I'm trying to reset the audio without restarting such applications.

Comment: Well. There is no real way to "reset" the audio output of external applications. Of course there are ways to interrupt applications to emit audio but there is no way to tell them to restart. One way would be to deactivate the audio device or another way would be start request exclusive mode for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is that possible with cscore? I would like to give it a try. Currently I'm restarting audiosrv service but it does not work every time.

Comment: Yes. You can open an audio device in exclusive mode with CSCore (only on Windows Vista and above).

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet as an answer? I couldn't figure out how to do it.